# Android: Retrieve thumbnail images from webpage

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am building an app that will ask the user for a url, and should present the user with a set of thumbnails to choose from, much like when you share a link on Facebook or Google plus. My question is this: how would I determine what images are available, and how would I download them as thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the URL provided, then look for the tag  and you are done. After that, you have found an image you can download.

To fetch and parse, you can look for some posts here (posts like "get html from url") and then use java Strings functions to find  tags (a `while` with something like `int position = html.indexOf("<img>";`). Otherwise, you can use Jsoup and avoid coding that much.

For download, I recommend searching here in StackOverflow ("Android download files") or in the Android developers web (http://d.android.com).

Cheers,
Aldo

Comment: Jsoup is amazing! Thanks for directing me to it. This is going to save me a lot of work.

Comment: I discovered it after coding a lot. I'm happy you won't have to!